# php javascript form serialize get data undefined index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, serialization

I want to call input value from javascript
My home page code :

```
<form method="post" id="form">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <label for="f_name">First Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f_name "id="f_name" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <label for="l_name">Last Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="l_name" id="l_name" value="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

....
javascript code :

```
$("#singup_btn").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url     : "register.php",
      method  : "POST",
      data    : $("form").serialize(),
      success : function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
    })
  })
```

...calling page code :

```
<?php

include "db.php";

    $fname = $_POST["f_name"];
    $lname = $_POST["l_name"];
...
echo $fname;
```

...error while click button, only last name (input) value defined

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: f_name in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\shop\register.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: email in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\shop\register.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: password in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\shop\register.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

please someone help me?
I stuck like more than 4 hours on this. Im learning javascript n php, n still newbie. Please help. thanks.

Comment: when ajax request sent, please check console. You can know whether data is sent with request or not.

Comment: how to do that sir?

Comment: @BillyAlfredo open developer tools in your browser (usually just f12 on windows) and check the console tab for js errors. Also check network tab to see what gets passed in the request to the server.

Comment: @MasterYoda no js error in console, just some css...

Comment: its a bug in the first input field, i've updated my answer.

Comment: Maybe its because you dont close your <form> tag with </form> or is that just missing syntax in the question?

Comment: chris solve my problem, thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a # You also have an error in your first input field.

```
<input name="f_name ">

shouldbe

<input name="f_name">

$("#singup_btn").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url     : "register.php",
        method  : "POST",
        data    : $("#form").serialize(),
        success : function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Change "method" to "type" also

Comment: @Chris It should still pick up the <form> element without targeting the Id as selector.

Comment: still same error, n i dont think javascript is the problem here maybe? because i can call last name value, but the others value cant.. idk why..

Comment: updated my answer, spotted another bug - you should also have said that in the first place it would have helped debug it faster.

Comment: Easy to do, glad its sorted :) if you are starting out developing, can i suggest you get yourself an IDE it can help eliminate many bugs before they become an issue along with many other features. (I use Netbeans)

Comment: I tested this with a click event in jquery to get the values of both textfields, that works just fine with the error in the markup. It seems the reason you were seeing this issue is to do with how jQuery serializes the form markup. Ill post an answer below explaining this but as its based on Chris answer please upvote him.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer with your explanation (credit yourself of course)

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$(document).on('click', '#singup_btn', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url     : "register.php",
        type    : "POST",
        data    : $("#form").serialize(),
        success : function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Please remove type="submit" from submit button and add type="button". It will work!

Comment: no, still get same error. only last name input value defined. others undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Serializing the form with a space in `name="f_name "id="f_name"` forces a `+` to be appended to the serialized value. This is why its not being picked up correctly server side.

---

**Expected server side value**

```
f_name=asd&l_name=asd
```

---

**Actual server side value**

```
f_name+=asd&l_name=asd
```

---

**see test below**

```js
$("button").click(function()
{
  //output values before serialization 
  console.log( "Result of f_name");
  console.log ($("#f_name").val() );
  console.log( "Result of l_name");
  console.log ($("#l_name").val() );
  
  //output values after serialization
  var serialized = $("form").serialize();
  console.log( "Result: Notice how f_name has an appended + in its key");
  console.log( "'" + serialized + "'");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="f_name">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f_name "id="f_name" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="l_name">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="l_name" id="l_name" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button"> test </button>
</form>
```

*Credit to Chris*